# How do I get an item from a ListView to not use a recycled view in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I currently have a buttons_row that displays conditionally in my item_exercise.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/item_exercise"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/exercise_name_value"
            style="@style/h5"
            android:text="@string/no_exercise"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/item_nav_image"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_nav_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_expand"
            android:contentDescription="@string/nav_expand_collapse"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_row"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/exercise_rename_btn"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_mic"
            android:contentDescription="@string/rename"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/exercise_delete_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_discard"
            android:contentDescription="@string/delete"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am using the ViewHolder pattern and when I run into issues when I delete an exercise from my list because the recycled view (with buttons_row displayed) gets recycled onto another item_exercise item.  I am wondering how I would fix this from happening?

Adapter.java:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.item_exercise, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.rithmId = 0;
        holder.exerciseName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.exercise_name_value);
        holder.renameButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.exercise_rename_btn);
        holder.deleteButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.exercise_delete_btn);
        holder.buttonsRow = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttons_row);
        holder.navImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_nav_image);
        holder.navShown = EXPAND;
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final BaseAdapter baseAdapter = this;
    final ActiveRithm rithm = (ActiveRithm) getItem(position);
    holder.rithmId = rithm.getRithmID();
    holder.exerciseName.setText(rithm.getName());
    holder.displayNavCorrectly();

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.toggleNav();
        }
    });

    holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //brings up confirmation dialog to delete this exercise/rithm
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}



static class ViewHolder {
    public int rithmId;
    public TextView exerciseName;
    public ImageButton renameButton;
    public ImageButton deleteButton;
    public String navShown;
    public RelativeLayout buttonsRow;
    public ImageView navImage;

    public void toggleNav() {
        Log.d(TAG, "navShown: " + navShown);
        if (navShown != null && navShown.equals(EXPAND)) {
            // display buttons
            buttonsRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // change image to be collapse
            navImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_collapse);
            navShown = COLLAPSE;
        } else {
            // hide buttons
            buttonsRow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // change the image to be expand
            navImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_expand);
            navShown = EXPAND;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sometimes when you delete a rithm, the holder does not display the correct navigation
     * This method makes sure that recycled views are being displayed correctly.
     */
    public void displayNavCorrectly() {
        Log.d(TAG, "displayNavCorrectly: " + navShown);

        if (navShown != null && navShown.equals(EXPAND)) {
            // Hide buttons and image should be expand
            buttonsRow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            navImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_expand);
        } else {
            buttonsRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            navImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_collapse);
        }
    }
}
```

I thought my displayNavCorrectly() method was going to fix things but it did not.  Do I need to store the 'state' of the UI inside my object? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to scrap recycling the view and inflate a new view each time. But that wouldn't be good for performance.

Overall the holder pattern is used to avoid calling findViewById to find views when the views will be the same. So you should not have rithmId and navShown in your holder.

After that you should set the state of the view. If the buttonrows visiblity can change you set it for every view. In your case it looks like you want the buttons to be hidden or shown. So your data (in your case ActiveRithm) should remember that, not your holders.

So when you get your object use it to set the current state of the current view

```
final ActiveRithm rithm = (ActiveRithm) getItem(position);
if (rithm.showingButtons) {
     holder.buttonsRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
     holder.buttonsRow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

And then in your on click don't manipulate the holder but manipulate the holders views and your data's state.

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
          rithm.showingButtons = !rithm.showingButtons;
          if (rithm.showingButtons) {
              holder.buttonsRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           } else {
              holder.buttonsRow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was afraid that I was going to have to do this...it feels dirty to have to modify my POJO for UI purposes, is there some type of better pattern to do this?

Comment: You could have the adapter remember selected indices.
List<Integer> selectedRows = new ArrayList<Integer>();
and then in your getView check if they are selected.